# How many vertices do you need so that all squares are not directly connected?

Tags: graph-theory

Below you see an example of a bicubic graph consisting of faces with degree $4$ and $6$, which makes up the set of graphs of my interest, called Barnette graphs.

[image]

Some more examples, including this, are given in [DeLaTorre's "Investigation of Barnette's Graphs"](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/files/6313/5795/0203/DeLaTorreThesis.pdf). The list of examples stop at $20$ vertices. As you easily spot the six squares are grouped in pairs:
$\{(1,2,9,10),(2,3,8,9)\},\{(5,6,13,14),(6,7,12,13)\},\{(15,16,17,18),(17,18,19,20)\}$

> How many vertices do you need so that all squares are not directly connected?

As the cited Horton-Manvel-McKay theorem states:
*"Every Barnette graph can be generated up to isomorphism using the two operations shown"*

$\hskip1.0in$[image]

But I don't see how to use these operations to separate the squares finally...

Comment: I'm kinda sad because the captions in those images say "*... add the vertices and edges in red*", but the images are black-and-white.

Comment: @MikePierce I'm sorry. This is a screenshot of a black and white paper. Colors were not supported, so use your imagination...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is $20$: [Truncated octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_octahedron);

[image]